# Como listar arquivos de pasta na rede

Tags: windows, batch

> **Contexto:**
> Algumas vezes ao dia preciso colher informações de pastas na rede,
> onde a mesma tem varias subpastas e arquivos.
>
> **Necessidade:**
> Preciso colher essa informação mais rápido, dessa forma pensei em
> colocar um .bat na pasta de **SentTo** do windows
> (C:\Users\nomeusuario\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo).
> <sub>*Caminho utilizado no Windows7, outras versões do windows poderá ser outro caminho.*</sub>

Atualmente realizo isso via CMD pelo comando:

```
dir /s /b \\caminho-rede\pasta\pastaArquivos | clip
```

Então através do SendTo ao  clicar com o botão direito do mouse na pasta *pastaArquivos*, automaticamente teria as informações em meu clipboard.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da forma abaixo, funciona localmente, porém via rede não:

```
set caminho=%cd%
dir %caminho% /s /b |clip
exit
```

Entretanto me retorna:

> '\caminho-rede\pasta\pastaArquivos' CMD.EXE foi iniciado tendo o
> caminho acima como pasta atual. Não há suporte para caminhos UNC.
> Padronizando para pasta do Windows.

**Observação:**
Se possível gostaria que retornasse a lista somente dos caminhos de arquivos **.EXE** e **.ZIP**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para acessar caminhos UNC a partir do prompt de comando, o Windows disponibiliza o comando `pushd`, que cria uma letra temporária de acesso ao caminho (em ordem alfabética inversa a partir de Z:) e altera o diretório atual para essa nova letra/caminho.

Após utilizar o caminho, você pode utilizar o comando `popd` para limpar esse caminho da pilha de caminhos temporários.

A mensagem de erro de caminho UNC sempre irá aparecer durante a execução do script, pois como você irá dispará-lo através do *SendTo*, o caminho inicial do processo CMD.EXE sempre será inválido.

Também, devido ao caminho inicial, a variável `%cd%`, indicada no seu código para acessar o caminho atual do arquivo `bat`, não irá funcionar.

A solução é trocar pela variável `%1`, que obtém o caminho de rede a partir do parâmetro informado pela execução através do *SendTo*.

Para obter a lista somente de arquivos **.EXE** e **.ZIP**, uma solução possível é filtrar a saída do comando `dir` utilizando o comando `findstr` antes de enviá-la para o comando clip.

O script completo fica da seguinte forma:

```
set caminho=%1
pushd %caminho%
dir /s /b | findstr /i /e "exe zip" | clip
popd
exit
```

**Observação:** os caminhos retornados pelo script irão iniciar com uma letra de disco inexistente no sistema (temporária) e não com o caminho de rede. Exemplo:

Ao invés de: `\\caminho-rede\pasta\pastaArquivos`

Poderá aparecer: `Z:\pasta\pastaArquivos`

É necessário verificar se esse comportamento atende a sua necessidade.

Links para a documentação:

De como usar os comandos `pushd` e `popd`:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317379

Do comando `findstr`:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Realmente aparece a unidade temporária, `X:\pasta\pastaArquivos`, mas isso no meu caso não faz a minima diferença, resolveu meu problema e ainda se caso eu precisar alterar fiquei sabendo dos comandos `pushd`, `popd` e `%1` que não conhecia. Obrigado @Gomiero.