# Copiar arquivo para o ClipBoard usando PowerShell

Tags: powershell, área-de-transferência

Que comando devo usar através do PowerShell para enviar um arquivo para o Clipboard?

Já tentei esse comando: 
"C:\Teste.text" | Set-Clipboard

Porém esse comando copia o texto "C:\Teste.text" e não o arquivo para a memória.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que isto resolve o teu problema ;)

```
Set-Clipboard -Path C:\NomeArquivo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a forma mais simples seja usando os comandos `type` e `clip`:

```
type C:\NomeArquivo.txt|clip
```

Comment: Olá Gomiero, acabei de tentar a sua sugestão e apenas o nome do arquivo foi para o clipboard e não o arquivo em si. A minha necessidade é copiar o arquivo e não a string contendo o nome dele. De qualquer forma muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui, e copiou o conteúdo do arquivo no PowerShell e mesmo no prompt "normal" do Windows (cmd). Apareceu alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Talvez, esta outra resposta: [Como listar arquivos de pasta na rede](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109351/como-listar-arquivos-de-pasta-na-rede) também possa ajudar

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Não entendi. A pergunta não é como copiar o conteúdo do arquivo para o clipboard? Por favor, me oriente caso você não concorde com o comando usado na resposta, e eu posso excluí-la sem problemas.

Comment: @Gomiero descupe, me equivoquei na analise, ignore o comentario automatico.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Ok! Obrigado pelo retorno :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sobre qual das opções é a pergunta? **Arquivo? ou Conteúdo?**

> - **1)** Copiar o **Próprio Arquivo** (copiar e colar **arquivo**)
> - **2)** Copiar o **Conteúdo do Arquivo** (Copiar e colar **conteúdo**)

---

> - Para ações de **copiar/colar** o **arquivo** para o **`ClipBoard (Crtl+C)`** 
>     já visando **colar** (ou **renomea-lo/colando**) em **outro lugar**...

---

---

> **1) Copia o próprio arquivo para o ClipBoard** possibilitando **colar renomeando** ou não:

```PowerShell
# copia o arquivo para o ClipBoard # 
  Get-ChildItem Q115551.log | Set-Clipboard 

# ou via uso de alias # 
  ls Q115551.log | scb

# Colar o arquivo na pasta apontada pela variável %temp% com o nome "Colado.log" #
  Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList | Copy-Item -Destination $env:temp\Colado.log -PassThru

# ou via uso de alias #  
  gcb -Format FileDropList | cpi -Destination $env:temp\Colado.log -PassThru
```

---

---

> - Para ações de **copiar/colar** apenas o **conteúdo do arquivo** para o **`ClipBoard (Crtl+C)`**, e nessa ação, já visando **colar** esse **conteúdo** noutro **arquivo**...

---

---

> **2) Copia o conteúdo do arquivo para o ClipBoard**

```PowerShell
# copiar o conteúdo do arquivo para o ClipBoard (Crtl+C) # 
  Get-Content Q115551.log | Set-Clipboard

# ou via alias # 
  gc Q115551.log | scb

# para colar o conteúdo do arquivo num destino #
  ForEach-Object {Get-Clipboard} $_ | Set-Content $env:temp\Colado2.log 

# ou via alias # 
  % $_ {gcb} $_ | sc $env:temp\Colado2.log
```

---

---

> - Para apenas exibir/printar na tela o conteúdo do **`ClipBoard (Crtl+C)`**

---

```PowerShell
# para copiar o conteúdo do arquivo e listar na tela #
  Get-Content Q115551.log | Set-Clipboard ; ForEach-Object {Get-Clipboard} $_

# ou via alias #
  gc Q115551.log | scb ; % $_ {gcb} $_
```

---